# keep tab open on refresh with bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having different html page in every tab and i want the active tab active even after refresh using bootstrap if possible

```
<div>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#TypeSettings">Type</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#EvidenceSettings">Evidence</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#OverallTypeSettings">Overall Type</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="TypeSettings" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <div ng-include src="'Templates/AdminSettings/TypeSettings.html'"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="EvidenceSettings" class="tab-pane fade">
        <div ng-include src="'Templates/AdminSettings/EvidenceSettings.html'"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="OverallTypeSettings" class="tab-pane fade">
        <div ng-include src="'Templates/AdminSettings/OverallTypeSettings.html'"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add a jsfiddle please!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remember last opened tab by user, then you have add some JS logic. You can store user last opened tab in a cookie for example.

Comment: yes suppose to want to store it in local storage can you help me with the code in angular controller
I don't want to include any extra libraries